# Why does my query using LIKE perform a seq scan?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a table with 2.2 Million rows.

```
                                     Table "public.index"
  Column   |            Type             |                      Modifiers                      
-----------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 fid       | integer                     | not null default nextval('index_fid_seq'::regclass)
 location  | character varying           | 
Indexes:
    "index_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (fid)
    "location_index" btree (location text_pattern_ops)
```

The location is the full path to a file, but I need to query using the name of the folder the file is located in. That folder name is unique in the table.

To avoid `%` at the beginning, I search for the full path which I know:

```
select fid from index where location like '/path/to/folder/%'
```

Explain Analyze:

```
    QUERY PLAN                                                                                  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on index  (cost=0.00..120223.34 rows=217 width=4) (actual time=1181.701..1181.701 rows=0 loops=1)
   Filter: ((location)::text ~~ '/path/to/folder/%'::text)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 2166034
 Planning time: 0.954 ms
 Execution time: 1181.748 ms
(5 rows)
```

---

The question is not how to make a workaround, because
I have found that for my case:

When creating a `foldername_index`

```
create index on index (substring(location, '(?<=/path/to/)[^\/]*');
```

I can succesfully use the folder_name to query:

```
explain analyze select fid from index where substring(location, '(?<=/path/to/)[^\/]*') = 'foldername';

    QUERY PLAN                                                                                  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on index  (cost=600.49..31524.74 rows=10830 width=12) (actual time=0.030..0.030 rows=1 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ("substring"((location)::text, '(?<=/path/to/)[^\/]*'::text) = 'folder_name'::text)
   Heap Blocks: exact=1
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on foldername_index  (cost=0.00..597.78 rows=10830 width=0) (actual time=0.023..0.023 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ("substring"((location)::text, '(?<=/path/to/)[^\/]*'::text) = 'folder_name'::text)
 Planning time: 0.115 ms
 Execution time: 0.059 ms
(7 rows)
```

---

I have followed the [PostgreSQL FAQ](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_are_my_queries_slow.3F_Why_don.27t_they_use_my_indexes.3F):

> When using wild-card operators such as LIKE or ~, indexes can only be
>   used in certain circumstances:
>
> The beginning of the search string must be anchored to the start of the string, i.e.
>
> LIKE patterns must not start with % or _.
>
> The search string can not start with a character class, e.g. [a-e].

Everyting not the case in my query.

> C locale must be used during initdb because sorting in a non-C locale often doesn't match the behavior of LIKE. You can create a special text_pattern_ops index that will work in such cases, but note it is only helpful for LIKE indexing.

I have C Locale:

```
# show LC_COLLATE;
 lc_collate 
------------
 C
(1 row)
```

I also followed the instructions from this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452528/7365127) here on Stack Overflow, which is why I use `text_pattern_ops` which did not change anything. Unfortunately, I cannot install new modules.

So: **Why does my query perform a seq scan?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found the solution myself by thinking about it over and over again. Although it might be obvious for some people, it may help others:

`/path/to/folder` is actually `/the_path/to/folder/` (There are underscores in the path). But `_` is a wildcard in SQL (like `%`).

```
select fid from index where location like '/the_path/to/folder/%'
```

Uses seq scan because the index cannot filter *any* rows, because the part up to the underscore is the same for all rows.

```
select fid from index where location like '/the\_path/to/folder/%'
```

uses index scan.

Comment: I asked a similar question @dba and they told me this is a question for StackOverflow because it's not about adminstrating but using databases.

Comment: Thank you @RoVo. Make sure you `analyze` your table at least once a week.